# make k8s service not to create reverse DNS record

Tags: kubernetes

whenever we create a service in k8s, it will automatically create a forward DNS record and also a reverse DNS record for this service.

is there anyway to tell k8s NOT to create the reverse DNS ? we don't need it and it could cause problems when those deployments are using hostnetwork: true.

Comment: Why would you need `hostNetwork: true`?

Answer (score 0):

Based on the documentation I gathered, I believe that automatic creation of DNS is already configured by default since service signifies connection. The keyword notice is "default” wherein every deployment it comes with a default DNS. Here are the links I gathered[1][2][3]

[1][https://www.cloudsigma.com/kubernetes-dns-service-a-beginners-guide/#:~:text=Using a DNS system to,lightweight approach for service discovery](https://www.cloudsigma.com/kubernetes-dns-service-a-beginners-guide/#:%7E:text=Using%20a%20DNS%20system%20to,lightweight%20approach%20for%20service%20discovery). [2]https://medium.com/kubernetes-tutorials/kubernetes-dns-for-services-and-pods-664804211501 [3]https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/access-application-cluster/configure-dns-cluster/